# How to read the n'th byte of a value type

Tags: c#

Suppose I've got a value type defined like follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=40)]
public struct Storage
{
}
```

The only purpose of this class is to occupy 40 bytes of memory.  Is there a way to easily read the n'th byte?  For example, I would like to write this function:

```
byte ReadFromStorage(ref Storage s, int n)
{
}
```

and similarly for a write version.  I need the performance of this function to be as close as possible to the following C code:

```
return *((char*)s + n);
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why dont you use byte array if that is the only purpose of your structure

Comment: I'm guessing that your Storage structure is coming from unmanaged code, if that's correct, you may use [Marshal.ReadByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhkh8kh.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use unsafe code for this.

```
static byte ReadFromStorage(Storage s, int n) {
    var handle = default(GCHandle);

    try {
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(s, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        var arrSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Storage));
        var arr = new Byte[arrSize];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, arrSize);
        return arr[n];

    } finally {
        if (handle.IsAllocated)
            handle.Free();
    }
}
```

After doing some revisions back and forth and reading William's comment, it's just a call to [Marshal.ReadByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c9010bx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but that doesn't look nearly as cool as juggling handlers and try-finally-statements.

```
var b = Marshal.ReadByte(s, n);
```

Comment: OP's comment is "I need the performance of this function to be as close as possible to the following C code: `return *((char*)s + n);`" Clearly, that rules out allocating managed memory just to retrieve a byte in a structure.

Comment: I've changed the code into calling Marshal.ReadByte, which William mentioned in a comment on the question. Using unsafe code introduces unverifiable code, which this doesn't. But yes, indeed, it does not perform exactly as the C code.

Comment: And I changed back, since it kind-of changes the original answer a lot. Marshal.ReadByte seems like the simplest choice.

Comment: Thanks, Marshal.ReadByte() does look like the best solution.  I notice the documentation states that the struct has to be "in unmanaged memory".  Which is actually not the case for me, so I wonder what will happen.  In any case, I'll test it out later.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fixed Size Buffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) instead.

That said, there's nothing stopping you from doing the following in an `unsafe` context (given you are using explicit layout):

```
unsafe byte ReadFromStorage(ref Storage s, int n)
{
    fixed(Storage* ptr = &s)
    {
       return ((byte*)ptr)[n];
    }
}
```